# How can I check the partition list from Athena in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I want to check the partition lists in Athena.

I used query like this.

```
show partitions table_name
```

But I want to search specific table existed.

So I used query like below but there was no results returned.

```
show partitions table_name partition(dt='2010-03-03')
```

Because dt contains hour data also.

```
dt='2010-03-03-01', dt='2010-03-03-02', ...........
```

So is there any way to search when I input '2010-03-03' then it search '2010-03-03-01', '2010-03-03-02'?

Do I have to separate partition like this?

```
dt='2010-03-03', dh='01'
```

And show partitions table_name returned only 500 rows in Hive. Is the same in Athena also?

Answer (score 4):

In Athena v2:

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT dt
FROM db_name."table_name$partitions"
WHERE dt LIKE '2010-03-03-%'
```

(see the [official aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-glue-catalog.html#querying-glue-catalog-listing-partitions))

---

In Athena v1:

There is a way to return the partition list as a resultset, so this can be filtered using `LIKE`. But you need to use the internal `information_schema` database like this:

```
SELECT partition_value
FROM information_schema.__internal_partitions__
WHERE table_schema = '<DB_NAME>'
        AND table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
        AND partition_value LIKE '2010-03-03-%'
```

Comment: "information_schema.__internal_partitions__" supported only in Athena engine version 1, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-glue-catalog.html#querying-glue-catalog-listing-partitions

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Benzi! I've edited the answer to match both versions